# Android how to pass an Activity.class as an argument for a function

Tags: java, android

I recently moved to Android from Python and am stuck here.

This is my class declaration to create a common function for an Alert Dialog which accepts necessary parameters:

```
public static AlertDialog.Builder getAlertDialog(String strArray[],
        String strTitle, Activity v) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(v)
    .setTitle(strTitle).setItems(strArray,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

But I cannot call this function via this piece of code which gives me an error:

```
  getAlertDialog(strArray, strTitle, MakeCall.class).show();
```

The error is:

```
the method getAlertDialog(String[], String, Activity) in the type   MakeCallAlertDialog is not applicable for the arguments (String[], String, Class<TestActivity>)
```

How can I get this correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want to pass a reference to your Activity use: `MakeCall.this` (or maybe just `this`.)

Answer (score 35):

### call like this:

```
ButtonClickBySani(R.id.btnsehrabandi, sehrabandiActivity.class);
```

### Definition:

```
private void ButtonClickBySani(int ButtonId, final Class<? extends Activity> ActivityToOpen)
{
    Button btn;
    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    btn = (Button) findViewById(ButtonId);

    // Capture button clicks
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityToOpen));
            // Start NewActivity.class
            //Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityToOpen);
           // startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: will there be difference the 2nd parameter not adding final? I mean difference in performance

Answer (score 5):

Just create an activity object/instance like **new YourActivity()**.

```
public static void Redirect(Context context,Activity page) {

..... //code

context.startActivity(new Intent(context,page.getClass()));

((Activity) context).finish();
}
```

and use this method as

```
Redirect(Registration.this, new YourActivity());
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to pass `this`. If *this* doesn't work, use `MakeCall.this`.

```
 getAlertDialog(strArray, strTitle, this).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the instance. Use `this` or `SampleActivity.this`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
private void switchActivity(Class cls){
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, cls);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Call the function like this: `switchActivity(DestinationActivity.class)`

Comment: Call the function like this: switchActivity(DestinationActivity.class);

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thank you for your answer! If you find you have more information to add to your answer, consider editing it, instead of posting a comment. Comments are temporary here and can be deleted, so they should be used mainly to ask for clarification on a question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, each class you write will also have a `Class` class attached to it. The `Class` class will be used by the classloader etc.

As others have said you should use `MakeCall.this` instead of `MakeCall.class` because `MakeCall.this` will point to itself which is an Activity whilst `MakeCall.class` will point to MakeCall's attached `Class` class.