# How to create a method to start an activity?

Tags: java, android, oop

I have a switch case that starts different activities depending on user selection. I do not want to keep repeating the code for creating an intent like this:

```
switch(choice) {
    case "option1":
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity1.class);
    case "option2":
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivit2.class);
}
```

I want to create a function where I can pass the context and my activity like:

```
private void startMyActivity(Context ctx, Type what_do_I_pass_here) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Type.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have tried

```
private void startMyActivity(Context ctx,Class<Activity> cls)
```

but it's not working

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229324/android-how-to-pass-an-activity-class-as-an-argument-for-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public void startSpecificActivity(Class<?> otherActivityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), otherActivityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Usage:

```
startSpecificActivity(MyActivity1.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to define function like this

```
public void startActivity(Context ctx, Class<?> activityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, activityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and you can call it like this

```
startActivity(this, MainActivity.class);
```